# Cocoa retain single object from array

Tags: xcode, arrays, cocoa

In Cocoa, I get the array of windows of an app using the following code:

```
CFArrayRef windows;
AXError gettingWindowsResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues(app, (CFStringRef)NSAccessibilityWindowsAttribute, 0, 999, &windows);
```

Then I check some values of those windows and keep the `AXUIElementRef` of one of them in a variable of my class. At the end of the method, I release the `CFArrayRef` to make sure I don't have any memory leaks:

```
if (windows != nil)
{
    CFRelease(windows);
}
```

Though this makes it so that when I try to use the window I kept, I get a bad access error. So my question: is it necessary that I release the array? And if so, how do I prevent the bad access error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a retained copy of the "`AXUIElementRef`" of the one element you want to keep?

To do this, figure out the index of the element you want to keep, and then make another call to the "`AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues`" function, only this time just pass the index for the element you desire and a "`maxValue`" of 1.  For example, for the element at position 26:

```
AXError gettingWindowsResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValues(app, (CFStringRef)NSAccessibilityWindowsAttribute, 26, 1, &arrayOfOne);
```

Then you can safely call "`CFRelease`" on the "`windows`" array.

Comment: Hmm, kind of a silly fix, but it should work. Testing it right now! Thanks